# What does "that" refer to?

Tags: incredibles-2

In Scifi action movie *[Incredibles 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incredibles_2)*, Frozone meets Incredible couples:

> Frozone: Now, you know the offer still stands.
>
> Elastigirl: You're very generous, but there are five of us. We
>   wouldn't do **that** to you and Honey.
>
> Frozone: Well, door's always open.

What does "that" refer to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frozone's previous line is

> How much longer are you in this motel?

(Answer:  "Two weeks.")  Frozone is offering to host the entire Parr/Incredible family at his home, but Elastigirl does not want to cause him (and his wife) that much inconvenience.  Fitting five more people into a two-person dwelling is going to come with a lot logistical problems.  Places needed to be found for all of them to sleep; meal planning may need to change drastically; and (even when the visitors are your best friend and his family) it can feel awkward to have non-family in your private space all the time.

Comment: And bathrooms.  Especially with a teenager involved, the bathrooms.